# Why this code compiles and it gives runtime error when it executes

Tags: scala, stringbuilder

This Scala code compiles under Scala 2.13

```
val res = new scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder
"hello".foreach { c =>
  if (true) {
    (0 until 10).foreach( res += c )
  }
}
```

If you see the `foreach` method is missing argument for anonymous function. When it is executed it gives an exception `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` for `res += c` which is puzzling since `StringBuilder` should always be appendable.

Following code runs fine and there are no exceptions. The only change is adding `_` as placeholder for `foreach` parameter function:

```
val res = new scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder()
"hello".foreach { c =>
  if (true) {
    (0 until 10).foreach( _ => res += c )
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly this puzzler! http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-027

Comment: @som-snytt This can be very well answer as well.

Comment: @som-snytt This can be very well answer as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question lies in `String.apply()` or `StringBuilder.apply()` to be more exact.

You see, `foreach` expects a function. In more exact words, an expression which evaluates to a function.

So, it will first evaluate the expression to get the function then it will apply that function for `0 until 10`

so when you consider the first iteration of outer `foreach`, you have `c = 'h'` and following,

```
(0 until 10).foreach(res += c )
```

Here, `res += c` will return `res` after appending `h` to it.

So... the evaluated function is `res` or `res.apply` with `res = "h"`. Hence, the above is actually,

```
(0 until 10).foreach("h".apply)
```

So, `res.apply(0)` goes well... but `res.apply(1)` fails with `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score -3):

Please see the signature for

```
def foreach[U](f: A => U): Unit = {
}

(f: A => U)  this is a function, not an expression.
```